# ccmake update Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: compiling, cmake

Hi all (I'm new to ubuntu),

I want to install ANTs (https://github.com/ANTsX/ANTs/wiki/Compiling-ANTs-on-Linux-and-Mac-OS) on ubuntu 16.04 LTS which results in:  `CMake 3.10.2 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.5.1`

I've installed cmake 3.11.4,  the output of `cmake -version` results in 3.11.4, but doesn't install ccmake.

Therefore I did `sudo apt install cmake-curses-gui` which gives me ccmake 3.5.1...

Can someone please help me how to update to ccmake 3.10.2 or higher on ubuntu 16.04 LTS?
I'd appreciate any help.
I also tried to install cmake with `sudo make all` but it didn't install ccmake 3.11.4.

Edit:

I used `./bootstrap && make && make install` with `sudo`, after that I also tried it with `make all`.

I'd appreciate any help, best regards, Lucius

Comment: which command do you use when you said *I've installed cmake 3.11.4, the output of cmake -version results in 3.11.4, but doesn't install ccmake.* ? It can help a lot to find an answer

Comment: I used `./bootstrap && make && make install` with sudo, after that I also tried it with `make all`

Comment: please edit your question by adding this command line, it will help others members than me (because I'm not the better place to answer)

Comment: It doesn't look like `ccmake` is really necessary - it's just used to create an initial configuration and *possibly* to set `SuperBuild_ANTS_USE_GIT_PROTOCOL` to `OFF`, which you could likely do just as easily using `cmake -DSuperBuild_ANTS_USE_GIT_PROTOCOL=OFF ~/code/ANTs`

Comment: @steeldriver thank you very much for that working workaround, alltough it doesn't solve the ccmake update problem...

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the exact same issue while trying to compile ANTs pulled from Github on Ubuntu 16.04. Here is what I tried that worked for me:

1. Remove `cmake` and `cmake-curses-gui` packages from Ubuntu: `sudo apt remove --purge cmake`.
2. Download CMake from https://cmake.org/download/; I downloaded version 3.11.4 to `~/Downloads`.
3. Install CMake v3.11.4:

   ```bsh
   cd ~/Downloads
   tar zxvf cmake-3.11.4.tar.gz
   cd cmake-3.11.4
   ./bootstrap && make
   sudo make install
   ```
4. Verify that I've installed CMake v3.11.4:

   ```
   $ which cmake
   /usr/local/bin/cmake
   $ cmake --version
   cmake version 3.11.4
   CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
   ```
5. To compile ANTs, I followed @steeldriver's comment and didn't use `ccmake`. Instead, I did this:

   ```bsh
   mkdir -p ~/bin/ants
   cd ~/bin/ants
   cmake ~/Github/ANTs
   make
   ```

(I didn't set the environment variable `DSuperBuild_ANTS_USE_GIT_PROTOCOL=OFF`.)

ANTs just finished compiling and didn't give me the `CMake 3.10.2 or higher is required.` error anymore. Basically I got around this problem by not using `ccmake` at all. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I'm sure it will help other users encountering that problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just compiled the latest cmake (in order to compile ANTs) on both CentOS 6 and Ubuntu 16.04.  The build process for cmake will only create ccmake if it can find the ncurses dev files.  For CentOS 6 you need to install ncurses-devel and Ubuntu 16.04 you need to install libncurses5-dev and libncursesw5-dev.  After I did this, the "make" process for cmake created ccmake and I was able to build ANTs according to the instructions.

Comment: The point about libncursesw5-dev is what solved it for me. Not seen that particular point anywhere else!  May using cmake -DBUILD_CursesDialog:BOOL=ON also helped; not sure.